# complex sql statements in my database

Tags: mysql

In my database, I have four tables, restaurants, inspections and complaints, restaurant operators.

Restaurants has attributes rest_id, restaurant_owner_email and name_of_restaurant;

inspections has rest_id (foreign key to restaurant), date_of_inspection, total score and a pass/fail from inspection,

Complaints has rest_id (foreign key to restaurant) and description_of_complaint

Restaurant operators have email (foreign key to restaurant), and their name.

I'm trying to find a way to list all the restaurants in a given year (this will be an input by the user but for now lets say 2015) who have more than a certain amount of complaints (also user input but lets say 1) that have a totalscore less than some value (user input, but lets say 90).

This has confused me a lot for the last few hours now because it seems very convoluted.

```
select name, firstname, totalscore, max(idate) from 
restaurant r, operatorowner o, inspection i, complaint c 
where o.email = r.email and i.rid = r.rid and c.rid = r.rid
and i.idate like '2015%' and
1 < (select count(*) from complaint x where x.rid = r.rid)
and 90 > i.totalscore
group by name, firstname;
```

This is what I've got so far, but it is not quite right. It gives me an error saying my totalscore is not functionally dependent on the columns in the group by.

Also, max(idate) is not a good way of finding the maximum date as it gives multiple values.

Is there an effective way of dealing with multiple tables effectively?

Comment: How is the total score determined for a given restaurant if it has multiple inspections?

Comment: each inspection gives a totalscore. Every inspection is linked to another table of items in the inspection which the restaurant must pass each of them. If the restaurant fails any one of them, they fail. 
A restaurant can have multiple inspections, but I want the inspection that was in the year specified by the user AND the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has numerous issues.  I think you want an aggregation query with a bunch of joins:

```
select name, firstname, max(totalscore) as totalscore,
       max(idate), count(*) as numcomplaints
from restaurant r join
     operatorowner o
     on o.email = r.email join
     (select i.*
      from inspection i
      where year(i.idate) = 2015 and
            i.totalscore < 90
      order by idate desc
      limit 1
     ) i
     on i.rid = r.rid join
     complaint c 
     on c.rid = r.rid
group by name, firstname
having count(*) > 1;
```

Because a restaurant could -- in theory -- have multiple inspections in a given year, you have a problem with a cartesian product.  You don't specify what to do in this case, so it takes the last inspection during the year.

Comment: I'm trying to read through your code. What do you mean by "order by idesc desc"?

Comment: @AkshayShukla . . . That should be `idate desc`.

Comment: wow! it works with a few tweaks. I'm honestly amazed that you could do it so fast with so little context to the problem.